# Revert all Pull Request merges from a branch

Tags: git

I have this scenario:

```
branch A: 1-2-3 - 6 - a* - 7-8   -  b* - 11
branch B:      \-4-5-/     \-9-10-/ 

final A: 1-2-3-4-5-6-a*-7-8-9-10-b*-11 (current)
```

Is there a way to revert merges from Branch B (in order, so that I can again revert it back) so I have something like:

```
branch C: 1-2-3-4-5-6-a*-7-8-9-10-b*-11-a*(revert)-b*(revert)
OR  
branch C: 1-2-3-4-5-6-a*-7-8-9-10-b*-11-a*b*(revert)
```

I don't want to manually get the SHA and revert it individually. In fact, I have many such merges which is pain to do manually. So, what I looking is to know how to revert ALL merge commits from a certain branch (which my case is branch B).